# How can I test a microservice secured by ouath2 using jhipster registry swagger API

Tags: oauth-2.0, jhipster, keycloak, jhipster-registry

I have generated a microservice secured by oauth2 using jhipster 5.6.0 and I'm using keycloak. I have launched jhipster registry also using oauth profile. I can not test my microservice using swagger in jhipster-rgistry.

I'm able to log in in the registry using Keycloak. I wonder how can I test my microservice using swagger (API menu in Jhipster)? as it is returning this error now: 
{
  "type": "https://www.jhipster.tech/problem/problem-with-message",
  "title": "Unauthorized",
  "status": 401,
  "detail": "Full authentication is required to access this resource",
  "path": "/api/users",
  "message": "error.http.401"
}

I'm able to test my service by getting accesstoken using postman.

Comment: Can't you do it in the gateway?

Comment: Yes @GaëlMarziou I can test it in postman and using gateway but I wonder I should be able to test it using jhipster-registry swagger ui or this functionality is not there? as I can test all microservices using  jhipster-registry swagger ui when I make them secured using  jwt.